# A few questions regarding overloading stream operators in c++

Tags: c++, class, function, operator-overloading

I am working on a hangman program and I want to output a status report to the user after each guess. As I am using classes, I need to use a 'friend' keyword. I'm ok with the concept of classes and friends however I am struggling to implement it properly in my program.

The main issue is that the numbers of vowels is not being counted and the number of letters the user can try is not updating. The full alphabet is being displayed each time.

The code of my program is substantial and I'm not going to post all of it here. The issues I have are with the functions `remainingLetters()`; and `vowelCount()`. I have attached the relevant code snippets. This code will obviously not compile. I'm just hoping that someone might see an obvious mistake that I've missed.

```
**Hangman.h:**
{
public:
...
int vowelCount()const; //to be implemented
char* remainingLetters()const;//to be implemented
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Hangman &game);

private:
...
int vowel_count;
char secretWord[MAXWORDLENGTH];
char* remaining_letters;
}

**hangman.cpp:**
{
...
int Hangman::vowelCount()const
{
  int vowel_count = 0;
  int i;
  secretWord[i];

  for(i=0; i<strlen(secretWord); i++)
  {


if(secretWord[i]=='a'||secretWord[i]=='e'||secretWord[i]=='i'||secretWord[i]=='o'||secretWord[i]=='u')
    {
      vowel_count++;
    }
  }
  return vowel_count;
}

char* Hangman::remainingLetters()const
{
  char alphabet[26]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
  char *remaining_letters=new char[ALPHABETSIZE];

  for(int i=0; i<strlen(secretWord); i++)
  {
  for(int j=0; j<ALPHABETSIZE; j++)
    {
       if(secretWord[i]!=alphabet[j])
       {
     remaining_letters[j]=alphabet[j];
       }
    }
  } 
 return remaining_letters;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Hangman &game)
{
    out << "Number of guesses remaining is: " << game.numGuessesAllowed-game.numWrongGuesses << endl
     << "Number of incorrect guesses so far is: "<<game.numWrongGuesses <<endl
     << "Letters remaining are: "<<game.remaining_letters <<endl
     << "Hint: The secret word contains "<<game.vowel_count <<" vowels"<<endl;

    return out;
}
}

**main.cpp**
{
...
 cout << game;
...
return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah, this line : secretWord[i]. what exactly secterWord is supposed to be and where you initialize it ?

Comment: Have included secretWord in my code. It is a char array that is populated by a function at the start of the program.

Comment: You leak memory every time you call `remainingLetters()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the functions `vowelCount()` and `remainingLetters()` for the corresponding variables to be calculated (so that you can output them).

Also, `char *remaining_letters=new char[ALPHABETSIZE];` will allocate the memory for the letters and initialize each position with 0 -- which also happens to be the string terminating value.  So if the first position (letter `'a'`) is not set, `out<<game.remaining_letters` will not output anything

Moreover, the function `vowelCount()` defines the local variable `vowel_count` that hides the one in the class (member variable), so the member variable will not get updated (uless you explicitly assign the return value of `vowelCount()` to that member variable)  I suggest you delete the local variable declaration from the `vowelCount()` function and it will use the member variable, which is what you need

The previous paragraph also applies to the member variable `remaining_letters`

One more thing: the memory allocated with `new` is not deallocated automatically, and once you return from the function call, the allocated memory is lost (as in there is no way to access it again, but it still uses memory), unless you assign it when the function returns.  You will need to pari each `new[]` call with its corresponding `delete[]` call.  Better yet: allocate the memory in the constructor of the class and delete it in the destructor for the member variable

Note: yet another bug is in this logic:

```
for(int i=0; i<strlen(secretWord); i++) 
{ 
  for(int j=0; j<ALPHABETSIZE; j++) 
  { 
    if(secretWord[i]!=alphabet[j]) 
    { 
      remaining_letters[j]=alphabet[j]; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

you cycle through the alphabet and every time the current letter in secret word is not matvching, you assign to `remaining_letters`.  This will assignment will happen every time as there will be a letter in the alphabet that does not match the curent secretWord letter.

To fix this, you will need do something like this (note the inversion of the loops):

```
int secret_len = strlen(secretWord); // cache length, so we don't recalculate it
                                     // every time: secretWord does not change
for(int j=0; j<ALPHABETSIZE; j++) 
{ 
  bool found = false; // assume the current ABC letter is not in secretWord
  for(int i=0; i<secret_len; i++) 
  { 
    if(secretWord[i]!=alphabet[j]) 
    { 
      found = true; // but it was
    } 
  } 
  if (!found) // if it wasn't
  {
    remaining_letters[j]=alphabet[j]; 
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great input thank you. Just one thing, how can I prevent the first position being set as 0? Should I define it as 'a'? I'm not really sure what you mean by that. Also, Is it feasible to call the functions in the operator function? Instead of calling the functions in the main.cpp?

Comment: You can certainly call functions in the operator body, but it might slow it down needlessly -- usually it is a good idea to keep the function/operator body as lean as possible -- in this case if you want to output the `game` object more than once without any change in between, there is no need to call the functions -- although you could certainly do some caching to avoid recalculation, just don;t forget to invalidate the cache when something changes.  Regarding the string termination issue: you can keep another counter that is specific to `remaining_letters` and increment it when you [cont]

Comment: [cont] assign to the current position in `remaining_letters`.  This also brings up yet another bug: your remaining letter calculation is incorrect

Comment: That's great Attila thanks very much. Some very constructive feedback there. Will update the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you do not keep the vowels count in the class member `vowel_count`. You store it in a local variable `vowel_count` and return it but the class member is never updated.

Comment: How do I do that? I thought that once the function had the class name in it's prototype it returned the corresponding class member?

Comment: you declare `int vowel_count` in your `vowelCount()` method. you shadow your class member so the variable you return is actually a local variable which will be invalid after the method finishes. just remove the `int vowel_count` declaration from the method

Comment: Did that and got the compiler error:    "increment of member 'Hangman::vowel_count' in read only object"    What does this mean?

Comment: you decalred the method as const which means this method does not change the state of the object. In this case it is so remove the const.

Comment: It means that since `vowelCount()` is marked as a `const` function (see its signature), you are not allowed to change the state of the object (that is: member variables or call other non-const functions) in that function -- remove the `const` and it will work